# JPA query returns wrong result

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have implement my custom CRUD repository, which adds some additional functionality, like getting the first next picture after some date (I am using this to find next picture after some other picture). But for some reason, it does not return result that I would expected. Sometimes the returned picture is the same as used for search (date of this picture). I am 100% sure, that all my pictures has unique dateCreated.

Anyone knows what is wrong with my code?

```
public class PictureRepositoryImpl implements CustomPictureRepository {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public Picture next(Date date) {

    TypedQuery<Picture> q = em.createQuery("select p from Picture p where p.dateCreated > :date order by p.dateCreated asc", Picture.class);
    q.setParameter("date",date, TemporalType.DATE);
    Picture picture = q.setFirstResult(0)
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getSingleResult();


    if(picture == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class).info("Fetched nextpicture: " + picture.getId() + ")");

    return picture;
}
}
```

[image]

**Update:**
I am expecting to get the first picture after "2016-03-20", instead of it, I get the same picture.

Comment: `it does not return result that I would expected` - it would help if you posted an example of _what_ you'd expect and what you get instead.

Comment: im sure it will return the picture appropriate for the SQL that was invoked. And the SQL invoked was what?

Comment: I'm not sure here since we normally don't use it but AFAIK `TemporalType.DATE` could cause the date to be truncated to day precision (or at least something above millisecond precision). Thus if 2 pictures have been created on the same day (or at least very close to each other) you'd get the one that was created earlier and this would probably be the one you're searching the successor for. Try `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` instead.

Comment: @Thomas O have updated my question

Comment: so look at the SQL!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue, it seems that the main problem was not using Timestamp, see code below.

```
 TypedQuery<Picture> q = em.createQuery("select p from Picture p where p.dateCreated < :date order by p.dateCreated desc", Picture.class);
    q.setParameter("date", date, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);

    List<Picture> pictures = q
            .setMaxResults(1)
            .getResultList();
```